# Why you need to manually register classes via composer in in Laravel?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, controller, composer-php

I come from a CodeIgniter background and everytime I create a new controller, I don't have to register it by calling a program like composer.

Why this is required in Laravel?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually register controllers, what's it say when you `echo app_path()`?

Comment: The question is wrong. Rephrase it or revise your assumptions and delete the question ;)

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk how is it wrong?

Comment: @dave You do not need to `register` any controllers. So again, rephrase the question and tell us what problem you have exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Laravel uses the "Classmap" autoloading mode in Composer. With this, it scans the specified directories and compiles a class map. Because of this, you need to run `composer dump-autoload` when you add a new class, so that it can update the compiled class map.

However, it is fairly easy to use PSR-4 autoloading with Laravel. This autoloading standard requires you to follow stricter namespacing rules with your class names and filenames.

To use PSR-4, you'll need to namespace your controllers, models, etc. like this:

```
Yourname\Yourproject\Controllers
Yourname\Yourprject\Models
```

etc. You'll also need to change the controllers, models, etc. directories to be capitalized - Controllers, Models, etc., - to match the namespaces. Then, add this to your composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Yourname\\Yourproject\\": "project_dir/app/"
    }
}
```

This will map the `Yourname\Yourproject` namespace to the app directory. So, for example, to find the class `Yourname\Yourproject\Controllers\FooController`, Composer will automatically know to look in `app/Controllers/FooController.php`. At the top of `FooController.php`, write

```
<?php
namespace Yourname\Yourproject\Controllers

class FooController extends \Controller {
...
```

(Note: It's not required to namespace everything with `Yourname\Yourproject\`; it's recommended, but a simple `Yourproject\` will work as well.

You can still also add an autoload.classmap section to your composer.json for classes that don't follow PSR-4, but you'll need to run `composer dump-autoload` for them.

For more information on the various autoloading modes in Composer, [see here.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Comment: Good answer, it's annoyed me that it has encouraged my developers to use the classmap method for a project as their first introduction to autoloading. So much extra annoying work! Hopefully they'll convert the default installation of Laravel to fully psr4 soon.